# How do I achieve an even color on my pastry – without fats?

Tags: baking, bread, pastry, glaze

How do I achieve an even color of my pastry without using fats (oil or eggs)? Is it even possible? This patchy look kind of puts me off these otherwise decent pirozhki.

I baked them in a convection oven.

[image]

Comment: Can you explain why you need to avoid oil and eggs?  It will help people suggest valid substitutions.

Comment: @FuzzyChef Gilbert's syndrome

Comment: I fully understand your limitations and think this is an interesting question. Nevertheless, have you done the maths on how much fat really is in the tablespoon or two of an egg & milk wash you’d need for a batch of pirozhki? And yes it’s ultimately just cosmetics.

Answer (score 2):

A substitute for egg wash is to simply use plain milk or evaporated milk.

A popular vegan variant is a mixture of two parts non-dairy milk and one part maple syrup or agave nectar.

I am however not aware of a strictly non-fat variant.

Comment: Nondairy milks are usually fat-free (at least when not made from nuts)

Comment: @rumtscho careful of over-generalising. The oat milk I have here (Lidl own) has 1% vegetable oil added; other plant milks I've had all have a similar fat content, whether or not they're nut- based.

Answer (score 2):

An egg wash or similar is mostly cosmetic, but sometimes also altering the texture of the crust. The sugars and protein also aid in browning and can give a glossy surface.

A totally fat-free option would be a starch glaze/wash: starch & water cooked together to a kind of thin(!) paste and brushed on as a wash, either at the beginning or a few minutes before your baked goods are finished. This is related to the method where finished bread is given a quick brush or spritz with water and goes back in the oven to create a glossy sheen.

Caveat: While egg/milk/fat tends to keep the crust *soft*, starch makes the crust *crisper*.

Answer (score 1):

Barley malt or rice syrup or even watered down molasses are all sugars that brown nicely.

That's how many soft pretzel recipes do it.

https://www.thekitchn.com/how-to-make-soft-pretzels-cooking-lessons-from-the-kitchn-195974#post-recipe-11431

Answer (score 0):

It's something to be done with a great deal of care, but you could try dipping them in an alkaline bath like pretzels.

Strong alkaline solutions are caustic and can damage you, your cookware, your counter top, your floor, etc.  So if you want to try this, be aware of the risk and track down some clear instructions from a reputable source for how to do this safely.

Nice even browning probably isn't worth risking chemical burns but it is an option.

Comment: Funny how folks are more wary of alkalines over acids. A warm baking soda bath will do.

Comment: When it comes to cooking dangerously caustic bases see more use than dangerously caustic acids.  If sodium bicarbonate will give this effect then that's certainly worth a shot before jumping to sodium carbonate or sodium hydroxide.